# Parsing the XML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, api

I am getting the flight details from the expedia API, please check the link below for the XML format.

The result output contains Rateinfo then flight details as separate node and there is no relation between rateinfo and flightsegment. 
Normally I load the XML into dataset and use the dataset to populate the records, but in this case there is no relation between rate and flight segment, how will I parse this XML in C#. I need to show the user the flight segments and the corresponding rates.

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/air/200919/xmlinterface.jsp?cid=55505&resType=air&intfc=ws&apiKey=fc9hjrvrur9vr4y2dqa249w4&xml=<AirSessionRequest method="getAirAvailability"><AirAvailabilityQuery><originCityCode>MCI</originCityCode><destinationCityCode>CLT</destinationCityCode><departureDateTime>09/01/2011 01:00 AM</departureDateTime><returnDateTime>09/04/2011 01:00 AM</returnDateTime><fareClass>Y</fareClass><tripType>R</tripType><Passengers><adultPassengers>2</adultPassengers></Passengers><xmlResultFormat>1</xmlResultFormat><searchType>2</searchType></AirAvailabilityQuery></AirSessionRequest>
```

Comment: That link doesn't appear to show much.  But, generally, you can't go wrong with LINQ to XML.  If you have a schema, look at xsd.exe.

Comment: Is your API key suppose to be private?

Comment: @Pierre-Alain Vigeant: This API key is in test mode. I can generate new key when I go live. So not an issue.

Comment: @Nick: When I read the XML into dataset, I get three different tables, but there is no way for me to connect the values between tables. there is no relation between rateinfo and flightsegment (something like rateid or something), so I am not able to use using LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dataset represents relational data much easier than hierarchial data, which is what the xml represents, and that is probably the crux of your problem.

Linq2Xml is one option, or you could create a set of classes that are seriealizable and deserialize the xml into instances of the class, so then you can just iterate through the classes with foreach, or use linq on them.

I'm not saying this is the best way to go about doing what you need, but it is relatively tidy, and you don't need to deal with xml, just class instances.  I tested this with the xml you provided and it worked quite well, although I do think that the Linq2Xml method might be more performant - Not 100% sure though.

Assuming your xml is in a variable called sXmlResult:

```
public class Test
{
    public void Run()
    {
        //Load the xml and serialize it into instances of our classes
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(AirAvailabilityResults));

        System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(sXmlResult);
        AirAvailabilityResults results = (AirAvailabilityResults)ser.Deserialize(sr);

        //Now we can access all the data like we would any other object.
        foreach (AirAvailabilityReply reply in results.AirAvailabilityReply)
        {
            double dNativeBaseFare = reply.RateInfo.nativeBaseFare;

            foreach (FlightSegment segment in reply.FlightSegment)
            {
                int iFlightNumber = segment.flightNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Create the seriealizable classes to represent the xml.  
//I created these by infering the schema from the xml.  These classes may need some changes, if 
//they don't exactly match the actual schema that expedia uses
public class AirAvailabilityResults
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public AirAvailabilityReply[] AirAvailabilityReply { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public int size {get;set;}

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public string cacheKey {get;set;}

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public string cacheLocation {get;set;}

}

public class AirAvailabilityReply
{
    public enum SupplierType
    {
        S
    }
    public enum TripType
    {
        R
    }
    public enum TicketType
    {
        E
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public SupplierType supplierType {get;set;}

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public TripType tripType {get;set;}

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public TicketType ticketType {get;set;}

    public RateInfo RateInfo { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()]
    public FlightSegment[] FlightSegment {get;set;}
}

public class RateInfo
{
    public double nativeBaseFare {get;set;}
    public double nativeTotalPrice {get;set;}
    public string nativeCurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public double displayBaseFare {get;set;}
    public double displayTotalPrice {get;set;}
    public string displayCurrencyCode { get; set; }
}

public class FlightSegment
{
    public bool segmentOutgoing {get;set;}
    public string airlineCode {get;set;}
    public string airline {get;set;}
    public int flightNumber {get;set;}
    public string originCityCode {get;set;}
    public string destinationCityCode {get;set;}
    public string departureDateTime {get;set;}
    public string arrivalDateTime { get; set; }
    public string fareClass {get;set;}
    public string equipmentCode {get;set;}
    public int numberOfStops {get;set;}
    public string originCity {get;set;}
    public string originStateProvince {get;set;}
    public string originCountry {get;set;}
    public string destinationCity {get;set;}
    public string desintationStateProvince {get;set;}
    public string destinationCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How did you generate this class? I tried with xsd.exe and it is not generating like this? Please let me know.

Comment: I wrote the classes by hand.  I took a look at the xml output example and just wrote classes that would match.  You could probably do it with xsd.ex though.  If you have the .xsd schema files, you can use "xsd.exe filename.xsd /classes"  If you only have xml samples you'd have to generate a .xsd files by using "xsd.exe filename.xml" xsd.exe should be able to infer as much of the schema as possible from the xml and generate an xsd file, which you would then use to generate the classes.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ to XML as Braveyard mentioned above might help.  You could use LINQ to break down the XML and deal with one group of rate info and flight segment at a time.  If you use anonymous types you could make your own connection between one rate info and the associated flight segments, and then store that in the database.

Here is a rough example to get you going down that path:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
xDoc = xDoc.Parse(responseXML); // Parse will take a string and load the XDocument with it
                                // You can also use Load to load from a file, StreamReader, etc.

// First, grab a collection of all the AirAvailabilityReply
var airAvailability = from x in xDoc.Descendants("AirAvailabilityReply")
                      select x;

// Now loop through each of the query results in the collection
foreach (var available in airAvailability)
{
    // Get the rate info
    var rates = from r in available.Descendants("RateInfo")
                select new RateInfo {
                    NativeBaseFare = r.Element("nativeBaseFare").Value,
                    NativeTotalPrice = r.Element("NativeTotalPrice").Value,
                    // etc
                };

    // Get the flight segment info
    var segments = from s in available.Descendants("FlightSegment")
                   select new FlightSegment {
                       SegmentOutgoing = s.Element("segmentOutgoing").Value,
                       AirlineCode = s.Element("airlineCode").Value,
                       // etc
                   };

    // Now you can take RateInfo (should only be one) and the FlightSegments (should be a collection of FlightSegments) and put them into your database.
}
```

In the above example, I'm assuming you have two classes (RateInfo and FlightSegment) and you'll populate the properties with the corresponding values from the XML.

This is probably not the most efficient example, but hopefully it'll give you an idea of how to tackle this using LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic and powerful way of parsing xml in C# would be Linq2XML.It has really easy-to-consume methods and please check the answer below:

Answer (score 0):

The API indicates that the RateInfo node corresponds to all the sibling FlightSegment nodes appended. So you dont have RateInfo for 1 FlightSegment

Comment: First rateinfo corresponding to 4 flightsegments (2 flightsegments for incoming flight and next 2 for return flight). That is where my problem is I have 100 rateinfo and 456 flightsegments and there is no way to relate then after I extract into dataset